# get datagridview value while editing cell and add the to a Text box C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a datagridview and a textbox.

what I want is to get the value of cell while editing and display it on the textbox, just like TextChange event of textbox.

Thank you.[Datagridview and Textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IuiG.png)

```
private void input_rr_table_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) 
{ 

formula_bar.Text = input_rr_table.Rows[row].Cel‌​ls[col].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: You may want to write that code in `CellBeginEdit` event of the `DataGridView`

Comment: I did try that but not working. can you give me a sample code, here is my code

private void input_rr_table_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            
            formula_bar.Text = input_rr_table.Rows[input_rr_table.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[input_rr_table.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        }

Comment: Please mention this code along with your question in code-format. Its not comprehensible here.

Comment: done editing it.

Comment: I tried it in `CellBeginEdit` event and also in `CellValueChanged` event. The value after edit comes to the `TextBox` but only after you navigate to some other cell after edit. IMO we can't display the text during edits just like `TextChanged` event of a `TextBox`